# How to open ListPreference automatically when activity is started

Tags: android, android-preferences, listpreference

I have two activities - `MainActivity` and `PrefActivity`. `MainActivity` - activity with button, when I click on it, it refer me to the PrefActivity
`PrefActivity` - `preferenceactivity` with `ListPreference`.

How to open or click on the `ListPreference` automatically while `PrefActivity` is opening?

Answer (score 0):

Use [startActivityForResult](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html) to transfer control from MainActivity to PrefActivity.  Once complete you'll return control back to MainActivity.

That said, you'll typically only want to automatically direct users to preferences the *first time* they use the app.  In that case you can use [Shared Preferences](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html#GetSharedPreferences) to record that prefs have been set.  (E.g., flip sharedPref [boolean](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Boolean.html) value to true.)

Comment: OK, but HOW TO CLICK on the ListPreferenceautomatically while PrefActivity is opening